# Get attr value failed using DOM traverse

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul class="locations" style="height: 129px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
    <li class="selected">
        <span data-tocityid="1">kuala lumpur</span>
        <span class="to_arrow">
          <img src="images/pos/arrow.png">
        </span>
        <span data-fromcityid="2">singapore</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My jquery

```
$(document).on('click','#destination .locations li', function(){
    var fromCityId = $(this).find('span:first').attr('data-fromCityId');
    var toCityId = $(this).find('span:last').attr('data-toCityId');
});
```

I got `undefined`. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: In HTML `data-tocityid` and in JS `data-toCityId`. Use `.data('tocityid')`

Comment: fromCityId is :last and toCityId is :first in your html example. Change it and will work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `span` which have that attribute so change selector to `span[data-tocityid]` and `span[data-fromcityid]`. In case if there is only one element then there is no need of `:last` or `:first`

```js
$(document).on('click', '#destination .locations li', function() {
  var fromCityId = $(this).find('span[data-fromcityid]').attr('data-fromcityid');
  var toCityId = $(this).find('span[data-tocityid]').attr('data-tocityid');
  console.log(toCityId, fromCityId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="destination">
  <ul class="locations" style="height: 129px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
    <li class="selected">
      <span data-tocityid="1">kuala lumpur</span>
      <span class="to_arrow">
          <img src="images/pos/arrow.png">
        </span>
      <span data-fromcityid="2">singapore</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

The error in your code is that you were added `:first` and `:last` wrongly, you just need to swap them

```js
$(document).on('click', '#destination .locations li', function() {
  var fromCityId = $(this).find('span:last').attr('data-fromCityId');
  var toCityId = $(this).find('span:first').attr('data-toCityId');
  console.log(toCityId, fromCityId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="destination">
  <ul class="locations" style="height: 129px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
    <li class="selected">
      <span data-tocityid="1">kuala lumpur</span>
      <span class="to_arrow">
          <img src="images/pos/arrow.png">
        </span>
      <span data-fromcityid="2">singapore</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**FYI :**  You can also use `data()` method to get `data-*` attribute value.

Comment: it will select last last span, but last span doesn't have `data-tocityid` attribute

Comment: really? there are only 3 span above, pls check

Comment: which selects `<span data-fromcityid="2">singapore</span>`

Comment: @PranavCBalan you don't need the `:first` `:last` if you're selecting by data attribute - maybe update your answer to make this clearer

Comment: yeah, exactly, my toCityId is 2.